# CMD or Batch File; Remove ZIP file with the same name as current working folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a working directory for example; \ABC123\WIP\ABC_0123456789*.xml.
During a process the contents of ABC_0123456789 are ZIPPED outside of the current working directory; so in this example in the WIP folder;

The directory will now look like;

1. \ABC123\WIP\ABC_0123456789\
2. \ABC123\WIP\ABC_0123456789.zip

Is it possible to have a command which will obtain the folder name of "ABC_0123456789" (or current working directory) and "if exists" delete the ZIP "ABC_0123456789.zip" in the root (directory above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** :

Based on your comment, what you need is this:

```
del "%CD%.zip" 2> nul
```

It will delete zip-file if it exists and has the same name as current working directory. If it doesn't exist, `2> nul` will redirect the error message and you won't see it. You can still use the ERRORLEVEL to check if the zip really existed or not (will be 0 if it existed and 1 if it didn't exist).

If you'd rather check first if it exists or not you can use

```
IF EXIST "%CD%.zip" del "%CD%.zip"
```

this will only execute the delete if the zip exists

**EDIT2**: [@LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) let me notice something I forgot to add. When variables represent (part of) a path, it is very important to surround it with `"` in case it may contain whitespaces.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately, the name of ZIP will be dynamic based on the folder name.

Comment: so what you want is to check for the current directory if there exists a zip-file with the same name in its parent directory?  And not to check if a zip-file corresponds to a directory??

Comment: I updated my answer to what you said, I didn't understand your intentions quite well. My apologies

Comment: I'm a bit astonished that you got the answer checked, `%CD%` will contain the whole path, according to the question there can't be a zip file with that name (it includes a drive letter and backslashes). Even your edited answer is definitely wrong.

Comment: what do you mean with  "`%CD%` will contain the whole path" and that it is definitrly wrong? If the current directories path is "\ABC123\WIP\ABC_0123456789", `%CD%` will return `\ABC123\WIP\ABC_0123456789`. As @AdamWatton said the intention was to delete the zip-file in the parent directory with the same name as the folder, the zip-file's path should be in this case "\ABC123\WIP\ABC_0123456789.zip" which actually is the same as `%CD%.zip`. Isn't it? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: `%CD%` will always return a path from the root of the curret drive like `C:\Users\AWatton\Documents\ABC123\WIP\ABC_0123456789` if you try to delete ´%CD%.zip` this won't work. I regularly test batches for my answers if not trivial or mention otherwise.

Comment: For the example you gave it will work perfectly (I had tested it before I posted the answer with a simple .txt - file and tested it just now with a .zip file of a directory). But it is true that if the path would contain whitespaces, my answer wouldn't have worked. Thanks for letting me notice that. I've edited my answer and added double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line inside the WIP\subfolder:

```
for %A in ("%CD%") do If exist "..\%~nA.zip" Del "..\%~nA.zip"
```

In a batch you have to double the percent signs of the for var:

```
for %%A in ("%CD%") do If exist "..\%%~nA.zip" Del "..\%%~nA.zip"
```

The root refers to the very root `\` of the drive, you meant the parent directory.
**Edit** Better quote the `("%CD%")` in case of spaces in the path